# how to bind nstableview selection and bunch of text fields?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I am trying to build trivial OSX app that use core data (non document based application)

As you will notice I didn't post any code, since the app is done with binding so far.

**Here is what i have so far:**

I have 2 entities that have relationship between them.

One entity, named Product has only one attribute, named productName, and the other is Productdetails and has 4 attribues

Now... I have succesfully create the app that works with 2 NSTableViews that is I can add, edit and delete records. You select a product from the one NSTableView, you get the product details in the other NSTableView displayed.

**My problems starts here:**

I would now like to keep the NSTableView for the Product, but to have the ProductDetails entity values displayed in text fields, not in NSTableView.

I have tried to do it with 2 array controllers, as I have it while I used 2 NSTableViews, but i get () in the text fields.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Gave you a +1 and deleted my answer for now.  I don't see the issue at first look, but maybe someone else will.